# How to input a couple of arguments using Popen.communicate?

Tags: python

I have installed the `Vienna` package to use it with a Python program. I was using an instruction called `RNAcofold` that allows the input of two sequences joined by `&`. The program I made is the following:

```
rna1="GCGCUUCG&CCGCGCGCC"
p = subprocess.Popen('RNAcofold.exe', stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,shell=True,
                     env={'PATH': 'D:\\ViennaRNAPackage'})
answer = p.communicate(rna1.encode())
```

The problem that I have is when I want to use another command, but this one uses two arguments; something like this:

```
rna1="GCGCUUCGCCGCGCGCC"
rna2="GCGCUUCGCCGCGCGCA"
p = subprocess.Popen('RNAduplex.exe', stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,shell=True,
                     env={'PATH': 'D:\\ViennaRNAPackage'})

answer = p.communicate(rna1.encode(),rna2.encode())
print (answer)
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'bytes'
```

The question that I have is: How can I communicate with this program if it receives two arguments? When I use it in the `cmd` prompt I should enter each sequence in a different line.

Comment: join both strings to create one string. And use `'\n'` between them.

Comment: use `help(p.communicate)` and you see `communicate(input=None, timeout=None)` and it means it expectes only one string/input. Second value is treated as `timeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create one string.

If program expect values in new lines then use `\n`

```
rna1="GCGCUUCGCCGCGCGCC"
rna2="GCGCUUCGCCGCGCGCA"

text = rna1 + "\n" + rna2

answer = p.communicate(text.encode())
```

---

If you run

```
help(p.communicate)
```

then you see

```
communicate(input=None, timeout=None)
```

and it means it expects only one string/input.

Second value is treated as `timeout` which has to be `float` or `int`.

---

**EDIT:**

I tested it with script `input.py`

```
number = 0
try:
    while True:
        data = input()
        number += 1
        print(number, data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stoped by Ctrl+C')
except EOFError:
    print('Stoped by EOF')
```

and code

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('input.py', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
r = p.communicate('hello\nworld'.encode())

print(r[0].decode())
```

Result:

```
1 hello
2 world
Stoped by EOF
```

Comment: thank  @furas I tried that but there was an error, it get solved after I restarted the kernel.